# How to make a number of method calls act as one transactional unit of work

Tags: java, spring, exception, transactions

I am working on an application server using java and Spring and I would like to group a number of method calls into a single unit work.

One particular flow involves the creation a new business related entity which involves the following separate operations / call outs from my application server:

- call out to database
- call out to in memory cache
- call out to another application server

I have one separate service for each of the above operations where each service throws a specific checked exception. Currently I am calling the above operation within the one try catch block with a specific catch for each exception in which I attempt a rollback.

Due to the rollback the code is not the cleanest and I'd prefer if there was some pattern / cleaner way of grouping the above into one unit of work (transaction) which can be rolled back.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you showed your code, and told us what you don't like about it, rather than describing it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides transaction support through demarcation.  Here is an article detailing how to use it for a similar use case:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/xa-transactions-2-phase-commit

Comment: Link-only answers are usually not acceptable on Stackoverflow because the the link may eventually become broken, rendering this answer useless. Either write the solution (indicated by the article), or post this link as a comment (minimum 10 reputation). See [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information